# Copying google spreadsheet columns from one spreadsheet to another with a script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to be able to copy a colum (well 3) from a spreadsheet to another spreadsheet (google docs spreadsheets). I'd also like there to be some sort of trigger that looks for modifications and automatically copies them to the new spreadsheet.

here is the code I have, that is not working! Thanks!

```
function copytest()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AvxaM_p22RvwdHl2MFl4MkhteVhmVzFDY2FOblNpVEE");
  var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("A1:B2");

  source_range.copyTo("A1:B2");

}
```

I think its all working except the last line source_range.copyTo("A1:B2");
I'm new to this scripting business, so thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you need to get the values first: `source_sheet.getRange("A1:B2").getValues();`

Comment: Since you are new to Apps SCript, I suggest you run through the tutorials. See this one for working with spreadsheets https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Comment: I went through the tutorials, and they are helpful indeed. thanks for the heads up! I'd found them before, but never took the time to read throught them. It definitely helped!

Comment: I accepted your edit although it contains an error, see my edit below yours in the answer.

Comment: Is the Spreadsheet function =ImportRange() not appropriate for this purpose?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the `copyTo()` method works only when destination is in the same spreadsheet.
To copy data from one spreadsheet to another you will have to get the values (and whatever format, colors, fontsize...) from the source range into a variable (a 2D array or as indicated in the tutorial that Srik was referring to) and write it back to the target range.

for example :

```
function copytest()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AnqSFd3iikE3dEpHUGJod2xwbXRqU25wS25HWF9pdEE");
  var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("A1:B2");
  var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A1:B2");

  var values = source_range.getValues();
  var bGcolors = source_range.getBackgrounds();
  var colors = source_range.getFontColors();
  var fontSizes = source_range.getFontSizes();
  // make use of autocomplete to find other methods...
  target_range.setValues(values);
  target_range.setBackgrounds(bGcolors);
  target_range.setFontColors(colors);
  target_range.setFontSizes(fontSizes);
}
```

NEW UPDATED CODE IS AS FOLLOWS **(EDIT BY QUESTION AUTHOR)**

```
function copyTest()
{

//gets and formats data ranges, to and from sheets.
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("idspispopd1234567890");
var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("one");
var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("A2:A");
var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A2:A");

//gets then writes values defined in setup
var values = source_range.getValues();
target_range.setValues(values);

//for checking last row with data in cell and formatting range
var lastRow = source_sheet.getLastRow();  

//FOR MAIL
var emailAddress = "test@test.test";
var subject = "Compass import information from Montessori Community School";
var message = values;
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

}
```

---

**EDIT 2 (BY ANSWERER)**

to get a full column, change the range definition like this :

```
var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("A2:A");
var values = source_range.getValues();
var target_range = target_sheet.getRange(2,1,values.length,values[0].length);// use the array size to define the range because the target column A is not necessarily the same size at this time.
```

if you want to copy multiple contiguous columns just define the source sheet accordingly, in A1 notation column A+B+C would be `.getRange("A2:C")`;.

Try to use the integer definition for range, IMO it's more easy and more readable : for example a range of full columns A+B+C would be `sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),3)`

For non  contiguous columns it's becoming a bit more complicated.... maybe a new thread ?

Comment: what if we don't know the number of rows in a column, we just want to get them all? Thanks for your help! I'm looking to copy a complete column into the new sheet..

Comment: Okay, so your answer was great, but now I get the error "Incorrect range height, was 175 but should be 199 (line 14, file "Code"). I'm going to update my original post with the code I have now. I thought simply changing the amount of rows on the target document would work, although now I just receive error that it should be 199, instead of 100. Could I use the .getLastRow(); somehow to determine and set the target sheet to the right number of rows? With multiple columns to copy, should i recreate code for each column or is there a way to specify in the range more than one column? Thanks again!

Comment: wait a second, I'll update the code to avoid this kind of error

Comment: Thanks again for your help Serge. I'm working some more on this today.  I'm going to be needing this for non-contiguous columns. I will start a new thread!~

Answer (score 1):

I have found that it is easier to just copy the source_sheet to the target_spreadsheet, copy the necessary range using `copyTo` then `delete` the copied source_sheet.

```
 // 1. Open source sheet
 let spreadsheetFrom = SpreadsheetApp.openById(source_spreadsheet_id);
 let sheetFrom = spreadsheetFrom.getSheetByName(source_sheet_name);

 // 2. Copy source sheet to target spreadsheet
 let spreadsheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.openById(target_spreadsheet_id);
 let sheetCopy = sheetFrom.copyTo(spreadsheetTo);

 // 3. Copy range from source_sheet's copy to target_sheet
 let rangeFrom = sheetCopy.getRange('XX:YY');    
 let sheetTo = spreadsheetTo.getSheetByName(target_sheet_name);
 let rangeTo = sheet.getRange('XX:YY');
 rangeFrom.copyTo(rangeTo);

 // 4. Delete source_sheet's copy
 spreadsheetTo.deleteSheet(sheetCopy);
```

Answer (score -2):

Since you are copying the data into the other spreadsheet you have to specify the other spreadsheet's range object. So, instead of your last line:

> var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A1:B2");
>
> source_range.copyTo(target_range);

Comment: this is not a bad idea, the argument must indeed be a range but when using copyTo(), the target range and source range must be on the same spreadsheet. So this code won't work in this case.

Comment: True. If the ranges are in different SpreadSheets I would go with your solution.

Comment: thanks for your help boskic, Although I am working with ranges in different spreadsheets I appreciate the help!