# Transfer to another spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I don't know my way around very well yet. I made a script with a colleague.

It looks like this:

```
function Asservatenkammer01(){

  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var source="Asservatenkammer!B11:L11";
  var rowNumberToInsert=18;
    sheet.insertRows(rowNumberToInsert);
  var destination="Asservatenkammer!B18:L18";
    sheet.getRange(source).moveTo(sheet.getRange(destination));
  
  var source="Asservatenkammer!B16:L16";
  var destination="Asservatenkammer!B11:L11";
    sheet.getRange(source).copyTo(sheet.getRange(destination));
}

function Asservatenkammer02(){

  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var source="Asservatenkammer!B12:L12";
  var rowNumberToInsert=18;
    sheet.insertRows(rowNumberToInsert);
  var destination="Asservatenkammer!B18:L18";
    sheet.getRange(source).moveTo(sheet.getRange(destination));
  
  var source="Asservatenkammer!B16:L16";
  var destination="Asservatenkammer!B12:L12";
    sheet.getRange(source).copyTo(sheet.getRange(destination));
}
```

We planned to do it on a spreadsheet. However, we would now like to transfer the transfer to another spreadsheet. Does anyone have an idea?

greetings

Brakel

Answer (score 0):

Since `copyTo()` & `moveTo()` methods only work when the target and destination range are in the same spreadsheet, you can refer to an existing answer from [Copying google spreadsheet columns from one spreadsheet to another with a script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17144704) on how you can transfer data from one spreadsheet file to another.